# .htaccess rewrite everything to parent directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite every request to the parent directory.

This is the content of my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ../$1
```

Unfortunately this isn't working and causes a 'Bad Request' error. Is this possible?

Comment: What the log is telling?

Comment: Look for mod_alias: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html

Answer (score 1):

the .* should be caught between () this way the system knows it is suppose to "memorize" the expression as $1.

Comment: ok thanks, done that. But the rewrite rule is not still working

Comment: i use something like this to redirect everything to one index.php ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_\/]+)$ index.php?url=$1 so if you enter www.website.com/first/second/other it translates to www.website.com/index.php?url=first/second/other ... does this help

Comment: well, that rewrites everything to the index.php in the directory the .htaccess is in. I have the .htaccess in a subdirectory and it must go to the parent directory