# .htaccess - Rewrite subfolder to parent with access to other files in the parent

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to create a RewriteRule which would allow me to hide the subfolder name from the URL. It seems pretty straightforward, although I would also like to retain access to the files in the parent folder, and I can't work out how to achieve this and whether this would be possible at all. To make it a bit more clear, my file tree is as follows:

```
[root]
 L[parent]
   file1
   L[subfolder]
     file2
```

So what I am trying to do, is to be able to rewrite `http://example.com/parent/subfolder/file2` to `http://example.com/parent/file2` while still having access to `http://example.com/parent/file1`. So far I found possible solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17642122/htaccess-hiding-a-directory-in-the-url-while-preserving-other-files) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804973/htaccess-rewrite-everything-to-parent-directory), but neither of them work as expected. I also had a look at the Apache Aliases, but I am not sure I can use them in this case. Any suggestions please?

**Edit**: Here is the current .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /pico/
 RewriteRule sitemap\.xml \?sitemap
 RewriteRule ^parent?$ parent/ [R=301,L] ## Redirects the old file to the index with the same name
 RewriteRule ^parent/subfolder/?$ parent/ [R=301,L] ## Redirects the index of the subfolder to the parent
 RewriteRule ^old-folder/?$ parent/subfolder/new-file1 [R=301,L] ## Redirects the old index to a new file in the subfolder
 RewriteRule ^old-folder/old-file parent/new-file [R=301,L] ## Redirects the files in the old folder to a new file in the parent
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
 RewriteRule . index.php [L]
 RewriteRule ^parent/([^/]+)/?$ parent/subfolder/$1 [L]

</IfModule>

# Prevent file browsing
Options -Indexes
```

The rules with the comments are just examples, since I am moving the old content to the new site while changing the structure, so there are many more repeating rules just like the examples above.

Comment: Where is your current .htaccess file?

Comment: Just added it to the question

Answer (score 0):

Did you just try this? Put this in an .htaccess file in the root.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^parent/([^/]+)/?$ /parent/subfolder/$1 [L]
```

**Edit:**

Based on your comment I'm explaining what I put above. You said you wanted anything that is in the `parent/subfolder` to be read as if it is in the `parent` location directly. So that means `http://example.com/parent/file2` does **NOT** really exist. Because it actually exists in `http://example.com/parent/subfolder/file2`.

That is the purpose of the conditions. It checks to make sure that any request for `/parent/whatever` is NOT a real file and NOT a real directory, and if that is true it rewrites it to `/parent/subfolder/whatever`. So it is what you asked for but you're not using the rules the way I gave them to you. All you did was add the rewriterule line to the bottom of your file and it will never execute because this rule

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
 RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

will execute before `RewriteRule ^parent/([^/]+)/?$ /parent/subfolder/$1 [L]` and then it will never run. You can't just provide pieces of your .htaccess rules when asking a question because some rules will take precedent over others depending on their order. You need to provide all your rules as you just now did.

So you need to change your rules to this.

```
 RewriteRule sitemap\.xml \?sitemap
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^parent/([^/]+)/?$ /parent/subfolder/$1 [L]
 RewriteRule ^parent?$ parent/ [R=301,L] ## Redirects the old file to the index with the same name
 RewriteRule ^parent/subfolder/?$ parent/ [R=301,L] ## Redirects the index of the subfolder to the parent
 RewriteRule ^old-folder/?$ parent/subfolder/new-file1 [R=301,L] ## Redirects the old index to a new file in the subfolder
 RewriteRule ^old-folder/old-file parent/new-file [R=301,L] ## Redirects the files in the old folder to a new file in the parent
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
 RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot put an additional .htaccess in an internal folder since I am using Pico CMS with Twig where the content folder (the actual URL structure) is separate from the templates folder. In any case, isn't your rule rewriting the index of a `file1` folder to a file with the same name in the subfolder? This is not what I am after. I need to access files in both the parent folder and its subfolder as if they all were in the parent folder.

Comment: Then just change the rule a little bit and put the rules in the root .htaccess. I updated the answer.

Comment: Still nothing. I might not understand the logic behind it, but seems to me that you are rewriting all subfolders of the parent to one particular subfolder. Again, this is not what I need

Comment: Yes, you aren't understanding the logic because it's not doing what you think. See my update.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain your code, but it still doesn't work. It seems that now .htaccess is causing Apache to throw a 404 error, while previously, with a regular redirect the error was thrown by the PHP engine. I any case, I won't be able to confirm that your code works up until I figure out where the problem lies. It seems that for now I will have to abandon the idea of rewriting and stick to the current URL structure. Thanks for your suggestions anyway